# Using JOptionPane on an HTML/PHP page

Tags: php, html, integration, joptionpane

/I am trying to get a simple message to pop up.  I put the code in as I have seen on every tutorial page but it gets errors that I don't quite understand.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Store Notice!", "Shipping information...", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
</script>

</head>

<iframe src="http://www.site.com/index.html" width="701" height="1500"></iframe>
</html>
```

I have edited the site link out.

The error I get when viewing the code is:

> [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: JOptionPane  global code
>   (index.html, line 13)

Any ideas what I need to include to fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: JavaScript is not Java!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add `javax.swing` object in php/html file. How is this possible. 
Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more details on `JOptionPane`. **Java and PHP are different platform.**